# How to use SMOTE in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 class, but the first one has 94091 lines and the second 16937 lines.

I want to use `smote` packages and return me a result with 60% with class 1 and 40 % for the other.

```
data.train_smote <- SMOTE(situa_ence ~ ., data.train, perc.over = 100, k=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find perc.over that will satisfy

```
(1+perc.over) *16937 / ((1+perc.over)*16937 + 94091) = 0.4
```

perc.over = 3.70357 is pretty close.